# Using tf.keras.utils.Sequence with model.fit_generator with use_multiprocessing=True generated warning

Tags: python, tensorflow, multiprocessing, tf.keras

This is the warning I got:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:multiprocessing can interact badly with TensorFlow, causing nondeterministic deadlocks. For high performance data pipelines tf.data is recommended.
```

The Sequence subclass I wrote strictly perform load and read I/O jpg files. I guess as long as no 2 threads do it simultaneously on the same file, things should be ok.

I trained for a few epoch and so far, there's no error. But would like to get feedback if there's something potentially bad that could happen.

Answer (score 4):

Initially in the `TensorFlow 2.0` Version, there were issues with the `keras.utils.Sequence` with `multiprocessing=True` was causing a hang due to deadlock. Later in `Tensorflow 2.1` this Warning was added to address this concern.

```
# use_multiprocessing=False works.
# use_multiprocessing=True hangs in a deadlock situation.
model.fit_generator(generator, use_multiprocessing=True, workers=2)
```

You can ignore this warning since you are not doing any processing which will create deadlock situation.

Answer (score 2):

In general, a necessary condition for deadlocks is that a process has exclusive access to a resource, and is waiting for another ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock#Necessary_conditions))

That means that if your `Sequence` (or generator) class only holds access to a single resource (e.g. a `.jpg` image file), then no deadlock can occur. Also, if you are reading data from memory, with no locking (e.g. read-only data), no deadlock can occur (due to lack of exclusivity).

In other words: The warning probably does not apply, unless you are reading or modifying *multiple* data, in a thread-safe manner, in your `Sequence`, or generator.

Answer (score 1):

I trained two models with the same hyper-parameteres, one is classifcation and the other is regression model. The classification model is trained with multi_processing=True without any warning, while training regression model with mse loss, it gives the warning and slowely consumes whole memory and systems hangs. So, I had to turn off multi_processing and it worked consuming almost 50% of the system memory. Note that the same batch size was used for traning both models although the classifcation model has more parameters than regression model.

Comment: do you mind pasting any specific error you see? it sounds like the multi proc is doing its job and thus consume more memory? so this isn't really an error or bug?

Comment: Same warning as in the question.